# How to integrate $\frac{\int _{-w}^w\:e^{-\frac{x^2}{w^a}}dx}{\int _{-\infty \:}^{\infty \:}\:e^{-\frac{x^2}{w^a}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, gaussian-integral, error-function, gaussian

I have found $\frac{\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{w}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\text{erf}\left(-\sqrt{w}\right)}{\pi ^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ for $\frac{\int _{-w}^w\:e^{-\frac{x^2}{w}}dx}{\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\:e^{-\frac{x^2}{w}}dx}$. However, I need to find how raising $w$ to the power of $a$ will change the solution.

Comment: So what have you found then? The integral doesn't depend on $a$ so $w^a$ is just another constant.

Comment: Why not try a change of variables for the integrals?

Comment: What are $w, a$?

Comment: @an4s : But the bounds of integration are $\pm w.\qquad$

Comment: @JCAA $w$ and $a$ are constants $\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Why can't you denote $w^a$ by $u$ and use the same technique you used for $a=1$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy That is true but that does not pose problems for solving the indefinite integral first. As JCAA pointed out, a simple substitution should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \frac{ \displaystyle \int_{-w}^w e^{-x^2/w^a} \, dx}{ \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/w^a} \, dx}$$ $$ \begin{align} & u = x/w^{a/2} \\ {} \\ & u^2 = x^2/w^a \\ {} \\ & w^{a/2} \, du = dx \end{align} $$ As $x$ goes from $-w$ to $w,\,\,\,$ $u$ goes from $-w^{1-a/2}$ to $w^{1-a/2}.$ Thus we have $$ \frac{\displaystyle\int_{-w^{1-a/2}}^{w^{1-a/2}} e^{-u^2}\, du}{ \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-u^2} \, du }. $$ The factor $w^{a/2}$ in the numerator and denominator has canceled. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy. Just realised it's just the same substitution.